# should handle toString -The toString method should return the correct hierarchy (no reply)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a test and a lot of unit(hidden) tests were given , however I ran into this error with a block of my code. Can you all please help me out?

```
getString(comment) {
const authorName = comment.getAuthor().getName();
if (!comment.getRepliedTo()) return authorName;
return `${comment.getMessage()} by ${authorName} (replied to 
${this.getString(comment.getRepliedTo())})`;
}
toString() {
const authorName = this.getAuthor().getName();
if (!this.getRepliedTo()) {
return `${this.message} by ${authorName}`;
}
return this.getString(this);
}
}
```

**the error says:**
 *should handle toString
The toString method should return the correct hierarchy (no reply)*

**I am meant to follow this format:**
    No replied to:
    message + " by " + author.name

With replied to:
    message + " by " + author.name + " (replied to " + repliedTo.author.name 
    + ")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... it worked for me

```
 getString(comment) {
    const authorName = comment.getAuthor().getName();
    if (!comment.getRepliedTo()) return authorName;
    return `${comment.getMessage()} by ${authorName} (replied to ${this.getString(comment.getRepliedTo())})`;
  }
  toString() {
   if(!this._repliedTo){
      return `${this._message} by ${this._author.getName()}`;
    } else {
      return `${this._message} by ${this._author.getName()} (replied to ${this._repliedTo.getAuthor().getName()})`
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your test fails because you mix template literals and string concatenation, if you take e.g.:

```
 `${this._message} + "by" ${authorName}`
```

then a message will be inserted by the template:

```
`Heureka! + "by" Archimedes`
```

I guess it should rather be:

```
`${this._message} by ${authorName}`
```

Also `repliedTo.authorName` should be wrapped in `${...}`

Comment: Thank you so much, funny enough, i edited and updated it (now here), what you recommended was the former format i was using but still gave the same error.

Comment: ok, now i implemented `${this._message} by ${authorName}` the test error is also saying again, return the  hierachy(nested reply)